# How to only use the map() function on the top level array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For my `react-native` app, I want to use the `array map()` method.

I've got an Array, called `groups` with 2 Objects with this structure:

```
Array [
  Object {
    [key]: Object {
      "value1": xxxx,
      "value2": Array [
        "xxxx",
        "xxxx"
      ],
      "value3": xxxx
  },
  Object {
    [key]: Object {
      "value1": xxxx,
      "value2": Array [
        "xxxx",
        "xxxx"
      ],
      "value3": xxxx
  }
]
```

As you can see there is an array in an array. I want to use the map function() just for the top level array. How can I do that?

Comment: Because it logs twice

Comment: because there are two elements in the Array, which are the two objects. Thus, in that `map()` function, the value `data` is evaluted as the first object and then as the second object.
In both cases, the object contains a property `value2`, so it shows also its array. I mean, if I've understood correctly your question, the behavior is the one we shuold expect

Comment: @MatteoGesmundo ah, okay, I think I get it! So, how can I avoid this behaviour? Meaning, how can I use the map function just for the "outer" array?

Comment: Show the content of your mapper, your description makes no sense. If what is hidden by `... some stuff ...` is not needed to repro the issue, then remove it. Array.prototype.map will only iterate over the non empty slots of the Array on which it has been called. Once again, the premise sounds completely off.

Comment: Uhm.. You just can't. I mean, you are already iterating over the outer array: the fact is that the elements of the outer array include the inner array. Exactly, what is your goal here? Because, as I just said, you're already iterating over the outer array

Answer (score 1):

It will print like this only,

```
{ a: 'b', c: [ 'd', 'e' ], f: 'g' }
{ h: 'j', k: [ 'l', 'm' ], n: 'o' }
```

I will not be biased while printing at least. :P